# How do you debug tensorflow serving, what IDE do you use?

Tags: eclipse, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I have used eclipse with the bazel plugin but cannot seem to bind the binaries to the gdb debugger. How do you develop your own sources and servables without the ability to debug them?

Just looking for options on how this is done by other devs

Comment: did you do an online search??

Comment: Yes, I can do it currently by modding the eclipse plugin e4b for Bazel and dev in there, but it seems like there would be some standard used by devs that are extending Tensorflow Serving. My googling reached me to the above solution but its not the best (maybe), and surely other people out there have a better way of doing this. I more want to know if there is a nice setup of a c++ IDE integrated with Bazel that can autobuild/debug etc. I've no idea how other Devs/google devs do it currently, surely not how I am.

Comment: @CalDow How did you go about debugging tensorflow serving ? What is the IDE you used for it ?

Comment: I gave up in the end @SandeepReddyGoli. But i believe what I wrote above is a way to do it. using the bazel plugin for eclipse and building with debug info... I probably cant help more than that as i never really got it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build using `bazel build -c dbg <target>` to build a binary with debug info, then you should be able to attach to the binaries with `gdb`.